# find a word after finding a specific word in a string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find multiple values in a large string.
for example I want to first capture `currency=` values and ignore if nothing mentioned, then the next string in first occurance which start with `[@`

```
[Namex]
Name=jsdjsk
value=dfdfdf
currency=dollor
market=sfdsf
endvalue=xyz
[@1234#feagbdvsdf]
[Namey]
Name=jsdjsk
value=dfdfdf
currency=
endvalue=xyz
[@5777#feagbdvsdf]
[Namez]
Name=jsdjsk
currency=euro
market=sfdsf
[@98766#feagbdvsdf]
```

I am able to find the fist value for currency using below, but uable to get the next value..

```
re.findall('currency=(.+)', s)
```

I am expecting below results:

```
dollor, 1234

euro, 98766
```

Comment: updated string :

[Namex]
Name=jsdjsk
value=dfdfdf
currency=dollor
market=sfdsf
endvalue=xyz
[@1234#feagbdvsdf]
[Namey]
Name=jsdjsk
value=dfdfdf
currency=
endvalue=xyz
[@5777#feagbdvsdf]
[Namez]
Name=jsdjsk
currency=euro
market=sfdsf
[@98766#feagbdvsdf]

Comment: Please fix your formatting.  For now, voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that captures the desired values in two groups:

```
re.findall(r'^currency=([^\n]+).*?\[@(\d+)', s, re.M | re.S)
```

This returns:

```
[('dollor', '1234'), ('euro', '98766')]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/vTynYJ

Comment: Thanks for your time.. got the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Another option using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) and 2 capturing groups is to match currency and then repeat matching the following lines ending with a newline until there is al line that starts with `[@` and then match the following 1+ digits in the second group.

This approach uses the multiline flag only

```
^currency=(\S+)(?:\n.*)*?\n\[@(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3A5J9T/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/CXF2uo)

For example:

```
re.findall(r"^currency=(\S+)(?:\n.*)*?\n\[@(\d+)", s, re.MULTILINE)
```

Result

```
[('dollor', '1234'), ('euro', '98766')]
```